# file locking was not happening either in the server1 or server2 using spring poller

Tags: spring-integration

I have implemented the spring poller in my Application. My Application runs in two servers. I place the txt/pdf/xlsx files in the inbound folder. The same inbound folder is pointed by the two servers. Once I place multiple files like 10-15 files, both servers(both JVM's) were trying to pick the same file and **One server process the file and moves the file from inbound to inprocess** & **when other server tries the same and throws the FileNotFoundException**.

Is there any way to lock the file so other server may not be able to read the same file? (or) Is there any other solution to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` can be supplied with the `<locker>` sub-element. See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading):

> When multiple processes are reading from the same directory it can be desirable to lock files to prevent them from being picked up concurrently. To do this you can use a `FileLocker`. There is a `java.nio` based implementation available out of the box, but it is also possible to implement your own locking scheme. The nio locker can be injected as follows

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
    directory="file:${input.directory}" prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int-file:nio-locker/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan tried the above scenario. I am getting below Exception
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 27 in XML document from URL [vfs:/content/Example.war/WEB-INF/classes/beanExample.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Comment: Looks like you are using XML wrong way and there is not enough or not correct scheme declarations

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan - I tired the uisng file locking, but I am getting IOEXCEPTION : The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file. Can you please provide a sample example with file locking which includes inbound-channel-adapter, outbound-channel-adapter, integration-reply-channel, integration-error-channel and service-activator in the XML file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I can share only this: https://github.com/artembilan/spring-integration/commit/fe5d20e3650cc147d0e13af909347d0c2eb65279.